# Rails: Rendering a partial doesn't render the javascript code within it

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, extjs, partials

In my Rails 5 code, I have a partial that loads on a successful return of an ajax call. This partial has a div id which is for a grid that is loaded by ExtJS code in assets file. 
The first time the page loads, all the UI is rendered fine including the ExtJS grid. But any time after that, when the ajax call executes, though the partial loads, the grid doesn't load. 
The code inside Ext.onReady(function() doesn't execute unless the entire page is reloaded. 
How can I change this?

myapp/app/view/index.html.erb

```
<div id="test">                   
  <%= render partial: 'my_partial' %>
 </div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  function someAjax(){
    $.ajax({
       url: '/mycontroller/my_data',                     
       success: function(result) {
          $('#test').html(result);          
        }                       
    }); 

  }  
</script>
```

myapp/app/view/_my_partial.html.erb

```
<li>                     
    <span>Some data </span><span><%= @value1 %></span> 
  </li>
<br>
<div>
  <div id="my-js-code"></div>
</div>
```

myapp/app/assets/javascript/my_grid_code.js.erb

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux': '/ext/ux'
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
if(Ext.get('my-js-code')){
//code that creates a grid



Ext.define('mymodel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['mycol1','mycol2']
    });
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'mymodel',
        pageSize: 10,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            format: 'json',
            url: '/mycontroller/list',                
           reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: ‘result’,
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
    gridColumns = [{
            header: ‘My Col1’,            
            dataIndex: 'my_col1’        
    },{
            header: ‘My Col2’,
            dataIndex: 'my_col2’        
    }];

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            renderTo: 'my-js-code',
            store: store,                        
            columns: gridColumns
        });
});
```

myapp/app/controllers/my_controller.rb

```
def my_data
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :partial => "my_partial" }  
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If think this is caused by Ext.onReady method which might only fire once.

The second time, extJS framework is already loaded and therefore the callback wont get invoked.

One simple fix could be to check it via Ext.isReady property (bool).

docs:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#property-isReady
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-onReady

---

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true,
  paths: {
    'Ext.ux': '/ext/ux'
  }
})

var renderGrid = function (target) {
  if (Ext.get(target)) {
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
      renderTo: target,
      store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        proxy: {
          type: 'rest',
          format: 'json',
          url: '/mycontroller/list',
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'result',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
          }
        }
      }),
      columns: [
        {
          header: 'My Col1',
          dataIndex: 'my_col1'
        }, {
          header: 'My Col2',
          dataIndex: 'my_col2'
        }]
    })
  }
}

Ext.isReady ? renderGrid('my-js-code') : Ext.onReady(renderGrid('my-js-code'))
```

Comment: could you tell me how to use Ext.isReady ? Like where should I set it so that my js code invoked when the Partial is loaded?

Comment: Sure, i can try it, i assume this is not the full part of your javascript, because i can't find where you have defined the store and gridColumns. It would help if you would share the whole js part.

Comment: Thanks you for  you help. But how can Ext.isReady be set to true? When my partial loads, it is still set to false. In fact, it always seems to be set to false

Comment: Its readonly and maintaned by the framework, it will be set to true after the framework has been loaded. Thats why in case its false we wait for it, using Ext.onReady with a callback. It might be better to get rid of that in general, i think the Loader definition should only take place once, as well as the part which checks if the framework is loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213373/discussion-between-kavitac-and-devbnz).

Comment: So I ended up removing the grid div from partial code and instead added it to the main Index. From ajax success I call Ext.getCmp('mygrid').getStore().load()